# System.Web.MVC.dll still references Beta version

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, build, beta

I'm running a build of my solution from a different computer (build machine), and found out that that system is still referencing the Beta version of System.Web.MVC.dll. How can I get it to reference the 1.0 version of the dll?

Comment: I thought 1.0 was essentially a beta....

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to specify explicit dll version in config to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the project `csproj`? In VS, right-click > `Unload Project`, right-click again > `Edit {project}.csproj` then find the References section. See what it's referencing.